# Python won't close excel workbook

Tags: python

After I run the code, I cannot seem to open the generated excel file, because my computer says it is "open in another program". If I close python, then I can open it.

When I try to add "workbook.close()" to the code, I get the error "Calling close() on already closed file." So it seems python already closed it.

What can I do to be able to see my outputs without having to close python?

```
import pandas as pd

# Import data
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Desktop\work\charts\constraints.xlsx' , sheet_name='biggestobstacle')
print (df)


# File 2 is the new excel table with the chart. Hence, we keep the originals untouched. We create a new excel + chart.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("file2.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='biggestobstacle')

# Get xlsxwriter objects
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['biggestobstacle']

# Create a 'column' chart
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})
# select the values of the series and set a name for the series
chart.add_series({
    'values': '=\'biggestobstacle\'!$B$2:$B$8', 
    "name": "My Series's Name"
})
# Insert the chart into the worksheet in the D2 cell
worksheet.insert_chart('D2', chart)

writer.save()

# This last line generates an error.
workbook.close()
```

Comment: The `writer.save()` and `workbook.close()` do more or less the same thing. Hence, the warning (not error) about "Calling close() on already closed file". Just omit the `save()` line and see how you get on.

Comment: @jmcnamara thanks! I tried that too, but same issue. It seems, as far as python is concerned, it has closed the files either way. But either way, the computer is not accepting that the file is closed.

Comment: Can you build a [mre] that can be run by someone who doesn't have your `constraints.xlsx` file? Right now answers are necessarily speculative since nobody but you can actually run the program.

Comment: (BTW, this is probably a Windows-only problem; UNIXy systems allow multiple programs to have the same file open for write at a time, so I doubt anyone trying to reproduce your bug on MacOS or Linux will see the problem unless they're checking the file descriptor table or such).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.3/pandas/io/excel/_base.py#L584-L900

It looks like you just .close() and don't worry about the save()

From the excelWriter class

```
def close(self):
    """synonym for save, to make it more file-like"""
    content = self.save()
    self.handles.close()
    return content
```

Answer (score 1):

try using a context manager it handles closing files automatically
it goes like this.

```
with open("StockQuotes.csv") as csvfile:
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
        csvfile.seek(0)
        hasHeader = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csvfile.read(1024))
        csvfile.seek(0)
        print("Headers found: " + str(hasHeader))
        print(dialect.delimiter)
        print(dialect.escapechar)
        print(dialect.quotechar)
```

Comment: Does it automatically save before closing?

Comment: @Amiga500 yes it does as far as i use it